# MS Graph API "AND" criteria in $search

Tags: rest, odata, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I am using the [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview) and not getting expected results when using the AND criteria.

If i was to query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{UserGUID}/messages?$search="to:customeraddress.com"
```

I would get a result containing all emails from that customer.
However if i change the search criteria to

```
$search="to:customeraddress.ac.uk AND sender:myDomain.com"
```

or

```
$search="to:customeraddress.ac.uk AND from:myDomain.com"
```

some of the emails that were originally returned are now missing even though they are from the mydomain address.

Have i got something wrong?

I have followed information from the following locations:

- https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#search-parameter
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference
- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn774955(v=exchg.160).aspx

Comment: What happens if you do that same search in Outlook on the web? Do you see the same missing messages?

Comment: I get the same results when using the web version

Comment: Ok. Since you get the same results in the web UI, that tells me that you're not using the API incorrectly :). I'll forward this to our search team.

Comment: It may be that the messages you are missing don't actually have the SMTP address of the sender stamped on them. This can happen depending on the client that's used to send the message. Outlook in particular is one that commonly does this. Instead of the SMTP address, the user's Exchange distinguished name gets stamped in the sender field.

Comment: When looking at the emails both from the  MS Graph result (JSON) and in outlook all the detailed information is there (sender, from etc). Additionally this does not account for the missing emails when using the "From" field in the search. Could there be anything else? Thank you

Comment: Yeah, you wouldn't see this in Graph. You'd need to use a MAPI viewer (like MFCMapi or OutlookSpy) to see this.